# Comparing random forest vs step wise regression

Tags: random-forest

We have a dataset that we would like to compare the performance between random forest vs regression. However, due to the limited total amount of data, we used 5-fold cross validation with 5 repeats on the whole dataset. Also, we would like to limit the total amount of features inside the models. We wonder if we can do the following:

```
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", classProbs=T, savePredictions = T, number = 5, repeats = 5)
set.seed(1)
step_model <- train(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10, data = ourdata, method = "glmStepAIC", family = "binomial", direction ="backward", metric = "Accuracy", preProc = c("center", "scale"), trControl = train.control)
rf_model <- train(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10, data = ourdata, method = "rf", metric = "Accuracy", preProc = c("center", "scale"), trControl = train.control, ntree =  500, tuneGrid = repGrid)
```

One main question is that there is simple implementation of feature selection for regression (stepAIC); however, I could't find one for random forest that be simplly integrated in when using the caret package.